# Not Able to Parse ServerEventMessage from ServiceStack to C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, servicestack

I Am able to get first level of JSON but not second.

I am getting JSON from Here -

```
var client = new ServerEventsClient(baseUri) {
    OnMessage = e => analysedata(e),
}.Start();
```

And in this functin, I am trying to parse -

```
public string analysedata(ServerEventMessage test)
        {
            var parsed = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test));
            string p1 = parsed["Data"].Value<string>();
        }
```

Now p1 should be a string? But it is of type - `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue`

parsed["Data"] is JSON response sent by my server.
If I do `parsed["Data"]["event_id"]` Debug.Writeline does not print anything in output.

Documentation - https://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-server-events-client#assigning-callback-handlers

Comment: use the `Json` property of `ServerEventMessage`

Comment: @Jason I have updated the question. Please check now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `JObject.Parse` to parse the json

```
public string analysedata(ServerEventMessage test)
    {
        var parsed = JObject.Parse(test.Json));
        string p1 = parsed["Data"].Value<string>();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For the usage of JObject, you could check the code below. I used a JSON string for reference.

```
 string json = @"{
  'channel': {
 'title': 'James Newton-King',
'link': 'http://james.newtonking.com',
'description': 'James Newton-King\'s blog.',
'item': [
  {
    'title': 'Json.NET 1.3 + New license + Now on CodePlex',
    'description': 'Announcing the release of Json.NET 1.3, the MIT license and the source on CodePlex',
    'link': 'http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx',
    'categories': [
      'Json.NET',
      'CodePlex'
    ]
  },
  {
    'title': 'LINQ to JSON beta',
    'description': 'Announcing LINQ to JSON',
    'link': 'http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx',
    'categories': [
      'Json.NET',
      'LINQ'
    ]
  }
]
}
}";

        JObject rss = JObject.Parse(json);

        string rssTitle = (string)rss["channel"]["title"];
        // James Newton-King

        string itemTitle = (string)rss["channel"]["item"][0]["title"];
        // Json.NET 1.3 + New license + Now on CodePlex

        JArray categories = (JArray)rss["channel"]["item"][0]["categories"];
        // ["Json.NET", "CodePlex"]

        IList<string> categoriesText = categories.Select(c => (string)c).ToList();
        // Json.NET
        // CodePlex
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using [ServiceStack](https://servicestack.net/), using its [JS Utils](https://docs.servicestack.net/js-utils) is the recommended way to parse arbitrary json, e.g:

```
var obj = (Dictionary<string,object>) JSON.parse(json);
```